# split a column in multiple columns, but only keep two of them

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'AB': ['A1_B1_C1', 'A2_B2_C2']})
```

I want to split the column `AB` on the first two occurrences of delimiter `_`, but only keep the first two columns. In other words, the output has to be

```
         AB   A   B
0  A1_B1_C1  A1  B1
1  A2_B2_C2  A2  B2
```

Currently, I can do it with

```
df[['A','B', 'C']]=df['AB'].str.split('_',n=2,expand=True)
df = df.drop(columns='C')
```

But it seems wasteful. Any options where I don't need to create a column that I then have to drop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to select the first two columns of the output:

```
df[['A', 'B']] = df['AB'].str.split('_',n=2,expand=True).iloc[:, :2]
```

Output:

```
         AB   A   B
0  A1_B1_C1  A1  B1
1  A2_B2_C2  A2  B2
```